# How to make galley item to be shared

Tags: php

I have galley and images stay in folder `DomainName/images/1.jpg.` I want to add **facebook** and **twitter** `share button` for each image. So is it possible somehow to modify link, because i use function that share opened page or any better ideas if you have.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your actual question is here, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your post accordingly.

Comment: I use for example this:
function tweetCurrentPage()
so it tweet index.php not the picture. I want to have share for every single picture. Is there way to make picture Current page with keeping the look of the site but only getting pic url or i shall use another tweet facebook share function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create these links with php to share a url or a file!

```
<a href="//facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URL">facebook</a>
<a href="//twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=TITLE&url=URL">twitter"></a>
<a href="//plus.google.com/share?url=URL">google"></a>
<a href="//reddit.com/submit/?url=URL">reddit"></a>
<a href="//linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&title=TITLE&url=URL">linkedin"></a>
<a href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=URL&media=PICTURE&description=TITLE">pinterest"></a>
```

**only change URL, TITLE and PICTURE in urls.**

Comment: <?php
 echo '<a href="//facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://url/images/'.$x.'.png">';?>facebook</a>

I did this to the link and that works exactly how i wanted thanks a lot. Is there any restrictions from facebook on using links like that ?

Comment: No, i don't think!